# Smart Contract validate the transaction sent.

Tags: solidity

I was wondering how smart contract can validate the sender address.  That means the transaction is coming from the valid Ethereum address. Do we have to have any validation logic inside the contract. I know that the one who deployed the contract can be set as the owner but then how Dapp signs the transactions and smart contracts verify that it has come from the proper source.

Answer (score 1):

to call smart contract method, user have to sign the transaction with their private key as usual other transactions. The signer of the tnx will be the msg.sender in smart contract.